# Trouble with reading phone state

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I want to perform some operation (Pause game) in my application when a call came. But reading the phone state is not working. I have given permission(READ_PHONE_STATE) in the manifest. Nothing is happen when a call came.
Thanks.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
PhoneStateListener listener;
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
*
*
*
listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            Toast.makeText(SudokuGameActivity.this, "IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
         Toast.makeText(SudokuGameActivity.this, "OFF Hook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            Toast.makeText(SudokuGameActivity.this, "Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mpauseButton.performClick();
          break;
          }

        }
       };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you written the following line :

```
 telephonyManager.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: No... Is there any need of a broadcast receiver??

Comment: Follow this : http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html

Answer (score 1):

when your listener has be created, you need invoke `public void listen (PhoneStateListener listener, int events)' to listen.

also, you can try this:
create a broadcatst receiver handle the action `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`,

code example:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private TelephonyManager manager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (manager == null) {
        manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    }
    String action = intent.getAction();
    System.out.println(action);
    System.out.println("current phone state:" + manager.getCallState());
}
```

}