# How to get a Call state of a phone

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble with reading phone state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740035/trouble-with-reading-phone-state)

I want to get a call state of phone in my application. I am doing one application in which , When user dial to a number, then my application should come to know whether  other side phone is Busy, Not-reachable or power-off states etc. For this I used com.android.internal API's they are 
Call.java`<http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Call.java.html>`, 
CallManger.java`<http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java.html>` and 
Connection.java`<http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/internal/telephony/Connection.java.html>`. I created subclass of Call.java like this:

```
public class MyCall extends Call{   

  CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();   
  Connection c;
  Phone mDefaultPhone;
  private final ArrayList<Connection> emptyConnections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
  int size; 
  List<Call> ringingCall = cm.getForegroundCalls();

  @Override
  public List<Connection> getConnections() {             
  System.out.println("**value of list***"+ringingCall.size());      
     if(ringingCall != null && !ringingCall.isEmpty()){             
     System.out.println("inside if****");
     System.out.println("**call is not null***");
     System.out.println("value of call"+ringingCall);
     return  ((MyCall) ringingCall).getConnections();
   }
   else{
      System.out.println("**list is  null***");
          return emptyConnections;
    }       
  }
  @Override
  public Phone getPhone() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("**inside getPhone***");
  return null;
 }
 @Override
 public void hangup() throws CallStateException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("**inside hangUp***");
 }
 @Override
 public boolean isMultiparty() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("**inside isMultiparty***");
  return false;
 }
 public Connection
   getEarliestConnection() {
    Connection myConn = new MyConnection();
    System.out.println("inside EarliestConnection"); 
     List<Connection> l;
     long time = Long.MAX_VALUE;
     Connection c;
     Connection earliest = null;
     l = getConnections();
     System.out.println("value of connection is=="+l); 
     if (l == null) {
        return null;
      }else if ( l.size() == 0)
      {
         return null;
        }
     for (int i = 0, s = l.size() ; i < s ; i++) {
     c = (Connection) l.get(i);
     long t;
     t = c.getCreateTime();
     if (t < time) {
       earliest = c;
       time = t;
     }
   }
  return earliest;
  }
}
```

Here I am getting the ringingCall.size is 0 for that it is executing else part. And one more class is  CallUpdate.java.

```
public class CallUpdate {   

   Call myCall = new MyCall();   
   CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();
   public Object getCallFailedString(){

     Connection myConn = myCall.getEarliestConnection();
     System.out.println("myConn is  ******"+myConn);
     System.out.println("myCall is  ******"+myCall);    
     if(myConn == null){
        System.out.println("myConn is null ******");
        return null;
     }              
      else
        {
      Connection.DisconnectCause cause = myConn.getDisconnectCause();                        
       System.out.println("myconn is not null ******"+cause);   
        switch(cause){
             case BUSY :
                System.out.println("inside busy");
          break;
        case NUMBER_UNREACHABLE :
           System.out.println("inside un-reachable");
         break;
        case POWER_OFF :
           System.out.println("inside power off");
         break;  
          }         

        }
    return myConn;
 }

}
```

In this code getting myConn value is null. I called CallManger class is like this:

```
CallManager cm = CallManager.getInstance();
```

But when I print this getting null pointer exception. `System.out.println("value of cm"+cm);` why this exception? Can anybody tell me?

Comment: Look into logcat. CallManager seems like an internal service, and you might not have permissions to get access to it.

Comment: @Vikram thnks alot for ur rply. Internal service means what?

Comment: @Vikram: Can you tell me any other way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have an idea. One thing I can say, I don't think you should use the internal APIs, they are not meant to be used by developers.

Comment: check this question this will solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740035/trouble-with-reading-phone-state

Comment: Yes I tried with that code but it not give call states at other side.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot obtain call related info like user busy, phone switch off etc directly by accessing internal API. Android does not provide these details for security reasons.
All you can do is trace the Log. we have three kinds of logs, so you have to trace 
 "Radio Log" only.

It consist of solcited and unsolicited commands, which are nothing but instructions sent from phone modem to Android OS and vice versa.

There you will find the line: `onDisconnect Cause: XXXX` which will be answer to your question.

Comment: Where I will ger those logs? I think When I called to other number from my device should check in DDMS. Is am right?

Comment: simple use: Process mLogcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time -b radio");                and then reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
           mLogcatProc.getInputStream()));

Comment: :Thanks for ur reply. I got "Radio Log". I checked it for three states. When targeted number is(accepted, rejected and power-off). always getting onDisconnect cause:Local.

Answer (score 0):

you really should take a look at the code in PhoneApp.java. tracing this line, you will find out that  'cm = CallManager.getInstance()'  is useless .  the key to this problem is GsmCall.java and GsmCallTracker

Comment: Can u tell me in proper way. I am not getting your point